# Google analytics is not registering anything from ReactGa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, router

I've set up ReactGa in my app.js file and double checked my google analytics ID is correct for my website, but I'm still not getting any pageviews reflected in my google analytics dashboard. I have a feeling this has to do with react-router, but I'm not sure how to debug ReactGa.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactGa from "react-ga";

//import CSS
import "./App.css";

//import components
import AboutMePage from "./components/about-me-page/AboutMePage";
import MyWorkPage from "./components/my-work-page/MyWorkPage";

function App() {
  //Google analytics
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGa.initialize("**removed for stack overflow**");
    //monitor page views
    ReactGa.pageview("/");
    ReactGa.pageview("/my-work");
  }, []);

  //states
  const [currentTags, setCurrentTags] = useState([]);
  const [videoPanelObject, setVideoPanelObject] = useState({
    hidden: true,
    videos: [],
    videoNumber: 0,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => <AboutMePage {...props} />} />

          <Route
            path="/my-work"
            render={(props) => (
              <MyWorkPage
                {...props}
                currentTags={currentTags}
                setCurrentTags={setCurrentTags}
                videoPanelObject={videoPanelObject}
                setVideoPanelObject={setVideoPanelObject}
              />
            )}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: When was this account created? How long did you wait?  Did you check the Realtime reports?

Comment: it was created a few days ago. nothing showing up in realtime reports either.

Answer (score 0):

It takes between 24 -72 hours for a new google analytics account to begin recording data.

Once your account is up and running.

When you send requests it takes between 24 - 48 hours for the data to show up in the standard reports but it should show up in the real time reports instantly.

Comment: the account has been running for longer than 72 hours and still nothing. also realtime data shows nothing.

Comment: ReactGa only works with Universal analytics  You did create a universal analytics account and not a GA 4 account right?